# Elasticsearch match multiple values and output result should be in same sequence of array element with sorting applied

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, match-phrase

I have an elastic search query:

```
{
    "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {'match_phrase': {'unique_chat_session_id': '1a8905a2-b328-4f57-8ce8-7ba2e43e138e'}}, {'match_phrase': {'unique_chat_session_id': 'f6a83c4a-8d2f-4f04-9eff-e753957fe9d2'}}
                ]
            }
        },
        "sort": [{"message_no": {"order": "asc"}}]
}
```

and output in below format:

```
    [
  {
    '_index': '',
    '_type': '',
    '_id': 'cPeZLG8BH6c52U24FH95',
    '_score': None,
    '_source': {
      'unique_chat_session_id': '1a8905a2-b328-4f57-8ce8-7ba2e43e138e',
      'message_no': 1
    },
    'sort': [
      1
    ]
  },
  {
    '_index': '',
    '_type': '',
    '_id': 'dPeZLG8BH6c52U24_X8k',
    '_score': None,
    '_source': {
      'unique_chat_session_id': 'f6a83c4a-8d2f-4f04-9eff-e753957fe9d2',
      'message_no': 1
    },
    'sort': [
      1
    ]
  },
  {
    '_index': '',
    '_type': '',
    '_id': 'cfeZLG8BH6c52U24FH_x',
    '_score': None,
    '_source': {
      'unique_chat_session_id': '1a8905a2-b328-4f57-8ce8-7ba2e43e138e',
      'message_no': 2
    },
    'sort': [
      2
    ]
  },
  {
    '_index': '',
    '_type': '',
    '_id': 'dfeZLG8BH6c52U24_X-w',
    '_score': None,
    '_source': {
      'unique_chat_session_id': 'f6a83c4a-8d2f-4f04-9eff-e753957fe9d2',
      'message_no': 2
    },
    'sort': [
      2
    ]
  },
  {
    '_index': '',
    '_type': '',
    '_id': 'cveZLG8BH6c52U24F3-c',
    '_score': None,
    '_source': {
      'unique_chat_session_id': '1a8905a2-b328-4f57-8ce8-7ba2e43e138e',
      'message_no': 3
    },
    'sort': [
      3
    ]
  },
  {
    '_index': '',
    '_type': '',
    '_id': 'c_eZLG8BH6c52U24GH8K',
    '_score': None,
    '_source': {
      'unique_chat_session_id': '1a8905a2-b328-4f57-8ce8-7ba2e43e138e',
      'message_no': 4
    },
    'sort': [
      4
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I want to make a query in which I will pass unique_chat_session_id in array format with exact match [1a8905a2-b328-4f57-8ce8-7ba2e43e138e, f6a83c4a-8d2f-4f04-9eff-e753957fe9d2] and I want to get the **output result in the same way in which the array is**. It should show all the result of 1st array element (here 1a8905a2-b328-4f57-8ce8-7ba2e43e138e) with sorting applied on msg_no. So my output result should be:

```
[
  {
    '_index': '',
    '_type': '',
    '_id': 'cPeZLG8BH6c52U24FH95',
    '_score': None,
    '_source': {
      'unique_chat_session_id': '1a8905a2-b328-4f57-8ce8-7ba2e43e138e',
      'message_no': 1
    },
    'sort': [
      1
    ]
  },
  {
    '_index': '',
    '_type': '',
    '_id': 'cfeZLG8BH6c52U24FH_x',
    '_score': None,
    '_source': {
      'unique_chat_session_id': '1a8905a2-b328-4f57-8ce8-7ba2e43e138e',
      'message_no': 2
    },
    'sort': [
      2
    ]
  },
  {
    '_index': '',
    '_type': '',
    '_id': 'cveZLG8BH6c52U24F3-c',
    '_score': None,
    '_source': {
      'unique_chat_session_id': '1a8905a2-b328-4f57-8ce8-7ba2e43e138e',
      'message_no': 3
    },
    'sort': [
      3
    ]
  },
  {
    '_index': '',
    '_type': '',
    '_id': 'c_eZLG8BH6c52U24GH8K',
    '_score': None,
    '_source': {
      'unique_chat_session_id': '1a8905a2-b328-4f57-8ce8-7ba2e43e138e',
      'message_no': 4
    },
    'sort': [
      4
    ]
  }
  {
    '_index': '',
    '_type': '',
    '_id': 'dPeZLG8BH6c52U24_X8k',
    '_score': None,
    '_source': {
      'unique_chat_session_id': 'f6a83c4a-8d2f-4f04-9eff-e753957fe9d2',
      'message_no': 1
    },
    'sort': [
      1
    ]
  },
  {
    '_index': '',
    '_type': '',
    '_id': 'dfeZLG8BH6c52U24_X-w',
    '_score': None,
    '_source': {
      'unique_chat_session_id': 'f6a83c4a-8d2f-4f04-9eff-e753957fe9d2',
      'message_no': 2
    },
    'sort': [
      2
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please provide the mapping and your query. Also be more clear with your question. Do the JSON fragments represent individual documents or snippets from a single document?

Comment: @DanielSchneiter I have updated my question with my existing query, current result and the final result which I want. Please let me know if you know anything about it. As I'm new in elastic search. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get back the documents in the sequence of `unique_chat_session_id's` as provided in the request, and then for a specific `unique_chat_session_id` ordered the documents by `message_no`.

As the first sorting criteria is not based on any logical order of values stored in your index, but solely relies on the position of the values in your request this cannot be accomplished with a query with `sort`-clauses.

You may want to consider using aggregations instead, where you first request the individual buckets in the order you want them, and then, for every single bucket, you request the top n hits.

**Example:**

```
POST /chat/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "chat_sessions": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": [
          { "term": { "unique_chat_session_id.keyword": "1a8905a2-b328-4f57-8ce8-7ba2e43e138e" }},
          { "term": { "unique_chat_session_id.keyword": "f6a83c4a-8d2f-4f04-9eff-e753957fe9d2" }}
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "messages_per_session": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              { "message_no": { "order": "asc" }}
            ],
            "size" : 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The filtered buckets will be returned in the same order as provided in the request. But please be aware of the fact that the `top_hits` aggregation is not meant to return hundreds or thousands of documents, as its name implies it is ideal to return the first couple of hits, which you can control with the `size` parameter within the `top_hits` aggregation.

As you did not provide the mapping I assumed the default mapping for string-fields, which is as a multi field with `unique_chat_session_id` being mapped to a field of type `text` (ideal for full-text search, but not really sure whether this makes sense for your use-case) and `unique_chat_session_id.keyword` being mapped to a field of type `keyword` (ideal for exact match search, which is what you need in your example.